# "non-finite finite-difference value" error in SARIMA models

Tags: r, arima, error-message

I am trying to fit different SARIMA models in R. I first tried to fit on the first 12 data points, I got an error; I thought seasonal differencing requires more data, so I changed it to first 24 data points, still I got an error. Now I am fitting it on the entire data, and still I am getting an error. Following is the code:

```
install.packages("MASS")
install.packages("forecast")

# Loading:
require(MASS)
require(forecast)

# Data:
nottem_ts <- ts(nottem, frequency=12, start=1920)

# Problem
p <- 0:2;  d <- 0:1;  q <- 0:2;  P <- 0:2;  D <- 0:1;  Q <- 0:2
comb    <- as.matrix(expand.grid(p,d,q,P,D,Q))
aic_vec <- numeric(nrow(comb))
for(k in 1:nrow(comb)){
  aic_vec[k] <- AIC(Arima(nottem_ts, order=c(comb[k,1], comb[k,2], comb[k,3]), 
                          seasonal=list(order=c(comb[k,4], comb[k,5], comb[k,6]), 
                          period=12), method="ML"))
}
aic_mat <- as.matrix(aic_vec)   
result  <- cbind(comb,aic_mat)
sorted  <- result[order(aic_vec),]
```

Is there any solution to this problem and why I am having following error?

```
Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  :
non-finite finite-difference value [2]
```

There are no errors if I remove seasonal part, thus I know code is correct and that's why I have not asked the question in a different place, such as Stack Overflow.

**Remark** Removing period=12 and using nottem_ts with frequency 1  makes the error disappear, so seasonality will be captured daily rather than monthly, does doing this make any sense?

**Comment** As far the analysis problem is concerned I can get rid of this by using fourier in Arima and do what I want to do, but I think it is interesting to know the reason of this error.

Comment: Is the precise model order at which the algorithm gets stuck  `2 1 1 2 0 0` (p d q P D Q)? This is where it gets stuck on my machine. If so, you could remove the big loop and ask just about that particular case.

Comment: @RichardHardy I removed that big loop, I thought it may get stuck at some other order as well, if it is getting stuck here, thus I asked in that way.

Comment: Alright, I get your point. I thought distiling the problem to a concrete instance will remove the extra trouble of finding out when exactly the problem happens.

Comment: This seems to me to be on topic since the error message is flagging up a statistical rather than purely coding issues

Comment: Quite possibly due to a coding issue ... in the optimizer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185387/non-finite-finite-difference-value-many-data-become-inf-and-na-after-exponentia and http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Non-finite-finite-difference-error-td877621.html and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84330/errors-in-optim-when-fitting-arima-model-in-r . Can you control the starting value (variable values) for the optimization?  Or perhaps specify bound constraints on the parameters being estimated to keep it from a bad region? Can you get intermediate optimization solver output?